# Expressing mocking humor

Tags: structure, word-choice, humor

This is my very first writing, so forgive me if i sound silly.

I am trying to express a thought from my mind where a mocking humor about "the excessive education but no common sense in our society" is required. So how can I improve this statement?

**In a world of knowledge at its heights**

Answer (score 2):

The reader will understand that it's mocking only from the context. Two primary ways to give context:

- Show events that demonstrate that this world does not exhibit "knowledge at its heights."
- Give the narrator's or viewpoint character's real opinions about the world and its level of knowledge.

If you give this context first, the reader will realize that the statement is mocking when it appears.

If you give the mocking statement first, an attentive reader will come to realize only later that the statement was mocking.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try this:

**In a world with knowledge at its height, we still forget where we put our keys every morning.**